# How to connect two ubuntu laptops using putty?

Tags: putty

I am trying to connect two Ubuntu laptops (server and client) using `putty`.

Here is the description:

- LAPTOP  A : UBUNTU SERVER 12.04 KERNEL : 3.2.0
- LAPTOP  B : UBUNTU 12.04 KERNEL : 3.2.0

Initially, made following attempts:

- Connecting Ubuntu server to the Internet (wireless network) using referred [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1740726).
- Installed `openssh-server` in the Laptop A, putty in Laptop B.
- Seen the different options in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- Shows `Access Denied` while trying to login in (after I have entered the correct password ) from the laptop B. Referred [link](http://naveenubuntu.blogspot.in/2012/08/receiving-access-denied-just-after.html).

Doesn't work. Please help.

Also tried this earlier:

```
ssh -v username@serveraddress -p 22
```

It says connection established with the server, but shows `Permission Denied` when password is entered.

Answer (score 3):

No need to use putty for this. You can use the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client
ssh username@serveraddress
```

Not sure this solves the problem, but you can try. This also handles your public keys, and should give you suggestions on what to do if there is a key error.

Answer (score 0):

if you get a permission denied error, there different possibilites for that:

- entered password is wrong.
- User cannot access the default shell.
- password logins are not allowed.
- many other possibilities with errors accessing files..

on the server type

```
tail -f /var/log/messages
```

right before executing the ssh command from the client, can give you essential information about whats going on. (you leave the tail program with Ctrl+C)